# C# MongoDB driver aggregate to get user with more tweets

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection called "tweets" in MongoDB as follow:

[image]

I want to use aggregation to get the user with more tweets published. I have tried this but it is not working.

```
        public void GetUserMoreTweets()
        {
            var aggregate = _collection.Aggregate()
                .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$User.Nickname" }, { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } })
                .Sort(new BsonDocument { { "count", -1 } });

            var result = aggregate.ToList();
        }
```

The result is a collection with one item but it is not what I expected.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Based on your screenshots the grouping key should be `{ "_id", "$User.NickName" }`

Comment: try to replace `NickName` instead of `Nickname`. Im not a C# guy